# Granting someone a wish in a humiliating manner

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests

Context: I'm an academic, and I often apply for grants in my home country. Its a tedious work, and the application has to prove that I am capable to finish the project I propose, not only at scientific level, but at management and accounting level. After passing successfully the evaluation process, a whole different process starts. It consists in you interacting with the grant agency. The grant agency assigns you a manager who makes sure your paperwork is in order. She (it's usually a she) has a very short fuse and seems hell bent on making your life miserable. To use a metaphor, it feels like you are a famished beggar and when you beg someone for food, they throw a half eaten chicken wing on the floor and then they tell you vanish because you're disgusting. In my case, the chicken wing is my slashed budget.

So, what would be a proper idiom, or expression to describe the process by which someone answers a request in a most humiliating, condescending manner?

Comment: I empathize with the situation and the simile.

Comment: This is close: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34597/is-toss-a-bone-to-somebody-a-popular-english-idiom

Comment: @JonLarby It's interesting that "throwing a bone" means something entirely different than tossing one.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your question sounds like you are talking about
*(making somebody) **jump through hoops**:*

> [the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-jump-through-hoops):
>
>   to do a lot of difficult things
>     before you are allowed to have or do something you want
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/jump-through-hoops):
>
>   to perform a series of difficult tests
>     to show that you are suitable for something
>   *There are so many hoops to jump through that a lot of people give up.*
>
> [Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jump_through_hoops):
>
>   Go through an elaborate or complicated procedure
>     in order to achieve an objective.
>   *‘the banks make you beg for a loan
>     and they make you jump through hoops to get it’*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jump%20through%20hoops):
>
>   to do a complicated or annoying series of things
>     in order to get or achieve something
>   - We had to *jump through* a lot of *hoops* to get a loan from the bank.
>
>     It shouldn’t be necessary to *jump through hoops*
>       to get a computer to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

**patronizing**:  to adopt an air of condescension toward : treat haughtily or coolly  [Merriam](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patronize)

and one, example [21 types of bosses](https://hiring.monster.com/hr/hr-best-practices/workforce-management/hr-management-skills/types-of-bosses.aspx) The Patronizing Boss:

> The patronizing boss is an old-school martyr. Didn’t you know? - he
>   built the company from the ground up! In fact, he made the chair
>   you’re sitting in. You, as an underling, need his holiness’s guidance
>   to see you through the most mundane and simple of tasks. His help,
>   however, always leads to – you guessed it - trouble. How to deal with
>   the King of Condescension? Try a little deflation. Ask him how is it
>   that someone as knowledgeable and talented as him is working for this
>   little company.